# Maintaining a data structure to have the values on links of ArrayList

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-list

This is my problem. I have a `HashMap` of  `Vertex` objects (mapping the name of cities to their corresponding objects.

I need to make a graph modeling the routes between these cities.

My current implementation has an `ArrayList` of `Edge` objects which have two `Vertex` and a path cost in each object. I then make an adjacency list using these sets of `Vertex` and `Edge` objects, i.e.

```
for (Edge e : edges) {
    ArrayList<Vertex> list = adjList.get(e.v1);
    if (list == null)
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(e.v2);
    adjList.put(e.v1, list);
}

edges:  ArrayList of edges having (v1,v2,weight) in each object
list :  The adjacency list for the vertex v1.
adjList: HashMap which has all the lists index by the vertex.
```

However in this model, my adjacency list does not store the edge lengths in the adjacency list, so that for each time when I want the edge length, I have to make a traversal of the `edges` list and find the object that has the two vertices in it.

I want to figure out if there is a clean way to include the edge lengths in this adjacency list itself.

Since my `Vertex` objects are made only once per vertex, I cannot store in them because storing 1 edge length in them would override all the other edges that come into it.

Comment: Hint: your question is somehow confusing. Your comment says that adjList should be a HashMap; but then it seems to be list?! In general: your naming could be improved!

Comment: @GhostCat adjList is a HashMap which contains all the lists for every vertex. In order to access each list for any vertex in O(1), I've made it a HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only one edge between the vertices `v1` and `v2` you could create a `HashMap<Pair<Vertex, Vertex>, Edge>` which maps which vertices are connected via an edge.

```
HashMap<Pair<Vertex, Vertex>, Edge> vertexMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Edge e : edges) {
    Pair<Vertex, Vertex> key = new Pair<>(e.v1, e.v2);
    vertexMap.put(key, e);
}
```

That way you can lookup an edge given to vertices via `vertexMap.get(new Pair<Vertex, Vertex>(v1, v2))`

`Pair` could be implemented like

```
class Pair<K, V> {
    private final K first;
    private final V second;

    public Pair(K first, V second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public K getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public V getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.first);
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.second);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Pair<?, ?> other = (Pair<?, ?>) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.first, other.first)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.second, other.second)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you graph is undirected you could also add the inverse of the relation in the loop:

```
for (Edge e : edges) {
    Pair<Vertex, Vertex> keyInverted = new Pair<>(e.v2, e.v1);
    vertexMap.put(keyInverted, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since an `Edge` object has two vertices labeled `v1` and `v2`, I assume that the graph is directed (edges are directed from vertex `v1` to vertex `v2`).

This being said, you can store the `Edge` itself in the adjacency list. You always know that the destination vertex is `v2` so there is no problem processing the list later in the code:

```
for (Edge e : edges) {
    ArrayList<Edge> list = adjList.get(e.v1);
    if (list == null)
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(e);  // add the edge which contains the adjacent vertex and the weight
    adjList.put(e.v1, list);
}
```

Comment: Even so, given vertices v1 and v2, it would still take O(n) time to look for the edge. (Get the value set of v1 and scan through it). Right now, we can do it in O(m) by scanning through the edges. It is a significant increase in efficiency though.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use a `HashMap` of `HashMap`s and save the distances with edge vertex stored as a value to the other vertex as a key. The approach is trivial but I can post an algorithm if you want.